# html input create li element how to set an id for the element

Tags: javascript, html, list, input, html-lists

I'm new with HTML & JS and I face the following problem:

I have an input in html that creates a new li Element (in combination with JS); is it possible to give every newly-created li element its own id? For example to delete an specific element?

For Example:

```
<li id="one"> .. </li>
<li id="two"> .. </li>
```

So far it creates only `<li> ... </li>`

I think it can be done with a `for` loop, but I have no idea how to use it in my case.

See my JS code below:

```
function NewEntry() {
    var Inputfield = document.getElementById("Inputfield");
    var AddButton = document.getElementById("AddButton");
    var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    Input.value = "";
```

I tried to insert a `for` loop into my code, but after that it doesn't add any elements.

```
function NewEntry() {
    var Inputfield = document.getElementById("Inputfield");
    var AddButton = document.getElementById("AddButton");
    var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++)
      li[i].id = 'abc-' + i;
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Input.value));
      ul.appendChild(li);
    Input.value = "";
```

Comment: Are you able to share your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" HTML? Without it, we can offer suggestions as to how this might be accomplished but they're not specifically applicable to your own code, because we can't see exactly what you're trying to do, or why you're caching some of those variables (`AddButton`) in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop needs curly braces to work properly:

```
function NewEntry() {
  var Inputfield = document.getElementById("Inputfield");
  var AddButton = document.getElementById("AddButton");
  var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    abcElements[i].id = 'abc-' + i;
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Inputfield.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  Inputfield.value = "";
}
```

Otherwise only the immediate line after the `for` statement will run as part of the loop.

There also appeared to be a typo - you had `Input` instead of `Inputfield`? But I notice there are some other variables used here which are not defined, so I assume some extra code was omitted?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply.

function NeuerEintrag() {
    var Inputfield = document.getElementById("Inputfield");
    var AddButton = document.getElementById("AddButton");
    var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length ; i++) {
        InputElement[i].id = 'InputElement-' + i;
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Inputfield.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        Inputfield.value = ""; 
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of elements inside the `<ul>` and use that as id for the `<li>`:

```js
var AddButton = document.getElementById("AddButton");
AddButton.addEventListener("click", NewEntry);

function NewEntry() {
  var Inputfield = document.getElementById("Inputfield");
  var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.id = ul.childElementCount;
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Inputfield.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  Inputfield.value = "";
  console.log(li);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Inputfield" />
<button id="AddButton">Add</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple means by which this could be accomplished is as follows, with explanatory comments in the JavaScript:

```js
// a generator function, to generate a constantly increasing counter:
const generator = function*() {
    // the initial value of the counter:
    let i = 0;
    // this loop causes the generator to return a number infinitely
    // though while the loop is infinite it yields one value and then
    // pauses until the next call; this is one instance where an
    // infinite loop is deliberate and not a problem:
    while (true) {
      // increments the value of i, and then returns it to the
      // calling context:
      yield ++i;
    }
  },
  // assigning a reference to the generator:
  counter = generator(),
  // a simple Arrow function that takes two arguments:
  // tag: String, the element-type to create, and
  // props: an Object of element-properties and values to
  // assign to the created element:
  create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props),
  // a reference to the various elements to which event-listeners are attached:
  list = document.querySelector('#list'),
  form = document.querySelector('form'),
  input = document.querySelector('input'),
  button = document.querySelector('#add'),
  // the addNew function, written as an Arrow function:
  addNew = () => {
    // caching the source of the text:
    const inputField = document.querySelector('input');

    // here we take the value, trim it to remove leading and trailing
    // white-space, and then retrieve its length; if there is a zero
    // length (so either nothing was entered, or only whitespace) then
    // we return here:
    if (inputField.value.trim().length === 0) {
      return false;
    }

    // otherwise we cache a reference to the element to which the
    // created <li> element will be appended:
    const ul = document.querySelector('#list'),
      // we call the create() function, here creating an <li>
      // element, and passing in an object of properties and
      // values:
      li = create('li', {
        // we set the 'id' - using a template literal string - to
        // the string of 'abc-' plus next-value of the counter:
        id: `abc-${counter.next().value}`,
        // and set the text-content of the element to the
        // trimmed value of the <input>:
        textContent: inputField.value.trim()
      }),
      // here we create a <button>,
      deleteButton = create('button', {
        // with its className set to 'delete':
        className: 'delete',
        // its text-content set to 'delete task':
        textContent: 'delete task',
        // and its type set to 'button' in order to
        // prevent the <button> submitting the <form>:
        type: 'button'
      });

    // we append the created <button> to the created <li>:
    li.append(deleteButton);
    // we append the <li> to the <ul>:
    ul.append(li);
    // and reset the value of the <input> to an empty string:
    inputField.value = '';
  };

// here we prevent form submission:
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault());

// here we bind an anonymous function as the event-handler of the
// 'keyup' event on the <input> element:
input.addEventListener('keyup', (evt) => {
  // if the, or an, 'Enter' key is pressed (note that evt.keyCode is
  // almost entirely deprecated now, but is here for backwards
  // compatibility, it can and possibly should be removed):
  if (evt.key === 'Enter' || evt.keyCode === 13) {
    // here we call the addNew() function:
    addNew();
  }
});

// we bind the addNew() function - note the deliberate lack of
// parentheses - as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
button.addEventListener('click', addNew);

// because we're adding the delete <button> elements we delegate the
// event-handling to the closest ancestor element present in the DOM
// on page-load, here that's the #list element. Here we bind the
// anonymous function as the event-handler for the 'click' event
// which bubbles to the <ul>:
list.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  // if the element on which the click event fired has an ancestor
  // .delete element (therefore it was fired on, or in, the .delete
  // <button>):
  if (evt.target.closest('.delete')) {
    // we navigate from the event-target to the closest <li>
    // ancestor element and use Element.remove() to remove that
    // element from the document:
    evt.target.closest('li').remove();
  }
})
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  inline-size: clamp(15em, 80vw, 1000px);
  margin-inline: auto;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

legend {
  border-inline: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin-inline: 1em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-block: 0.5em;
}

label input[type=text] {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#list {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#list:empty::before {
  color: hsl(0deg 30% 30% / 0.8);
  content: "A beautiful, quiet day of reflection...";
  font-style: italic;
}

#list li {
  background-color: lavender;
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

#list li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

li[id]::before {
  content: "#" attr(id) ": ";
}

.delete {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h2>To do list</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>New task</legend>
        <label>
          <span class="labelText">What do you want to do today?</span>
          <input type="text">
        </label>
        <button id="add" type="button">Add task to list</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/avmbtz8d/).

It's worth noting that there is one potential issue using a generator function to generate a counter for an `id` property; the counter will only ever increase, so if you have three elements `abc-1`, `abc-2`, `abc-3` and then delete those, and create another three elements those elements will continue from `abc-4`. So the `id` will be independent of the number of created elements. This may be a benefit in that a duplicate value can't be created, so there's little chance of a duplicate `id` being created by a generator.

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
- [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [Generator functions (`function*(){...}`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- [`while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and example. It helps a lot and give me stuff to try something new.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to have helped! Also, @Nico, it seems you accepted my answer and then accepted someone else's answer - and that's absolutely fine, you're free to accept whichever answer you found most useful - it's important that you know you up-vote as many answers as you wish (once you have sufficient reputation/karma), but you can only accept one answer to any given question, you can't accept multiple answers, however grateful you are to all those who offered an answer. :)